# C++ concatenating an unterminated char* to std::string

Tags: c++, string, character, delimiter

What is a good way to convert an *unterminated* char* into a std::string?  For example, upon completion of the following,

```
int bytes = recv(_socket, &_recv_buffer, recv_buffer_len, 0)
```

I have the address of the receive buffer, and the number of bytes it contains, and I want to concatenate it to a **std::string**.  (FWIW, I'm not working with multibyte character sets.)  The fallback would be to make the **_recv_buffer** one byte larger than **recv_buffer_len**, and set **_recv_buffer[bytes] = '\0'**, but I wondered if there were a less sloppy way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::string` has an `append` method that takes both a pointer to a string and a length:

```
string& append (const char* s, size_t n);
```

For you:

```
myString.append(_recv_buffer, bytes);
```

Editorial note: watch out for identifiers that start with `_`.  They're reserved for use by the implementation.

Comment: Even the single underscore?  I somehow thought that was a commonly used convention for instance variables.  Something else instead?

Comment: I personally use a single trailing underscore, `like_this_`.

Comment: From the spec: "Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace."

Comment: Of course, another big giveaway is the `this->` in front of it ... :)

Comment: @CarlNorum, that means such names aren't reserved if they're not in the global namespace.

Comment: That's true, but shadowing things is usually not a good idea either.

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.append(recv_buffer, bytes);` which should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string data(&_recv_buffer, &_recv_buffer + bytes);
```

And are you sure about the `&_recv_buffer`? If your buffer is a `char[]` or something similiar it must be `_recv_buffer`.